# SQL Sort on date (D-M)

Tags: php, date, mysql

I have a field in my database as text, which contain a D-M date value. The year is a new field. So ORDER BY year ASC is not that difficult. Now I wanted to also ORDER BY date.
Only problem is, ORDER BY year ASC, ORDER BY date does not work. I think because of the text field. Is it still possible to sort them on year, month, day ASC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING_INDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
... ORDER BY year ASC, SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, '-', -1) ASC, SUBSTRING_INDEX(date, '-', 1) ASC
```

- `SUBSTRING(date, '-', -1)` will give you everything after the `-` (the month).
- `SUBSTRING(date, '-', 1)` will give you everything before the `-` (the day).